# Convert String to NSDate always nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I want to covert from a NSString to NSDate object.
My string is : `@"01/01/2013`.

Here is the code to convert the string to NSDate:

```
- (NSDate*) formatDateTimeFromString: (NSString* ) string{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate* date=  [dateFormatter dateFromString:string    ];
    return date;
}
```

I debug into the function and see that the date object is always nil. Did I have any mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your date formatter is wrong (might be hard to see at first)

Change

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```